# Using a function to convert angles from degrees to radians in C

Tags: c

As part of a wider project I am given an angle in degrees that needs to be converted to radians for some calculation.

So far, I have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

feature1()
{
    double angle = 90.0000, angle2;
    angle2 = convert_to_rad(angle);
    printf("%lf", &angle);
}

double convert_to_rad(double angle_in_deg)
{
    double angle_in_rad;
    angle_in_rad = (angle_in_deg * M_PI) / 180;
    return angle_in_rad;
}
```

When compiling the file in NetBeans I get the following errors:

```
note: previous implicit declaration of 'convert_to_rad' was here.
error: conflicting types for 'convert_to_rad
```

Comment: Note that your `feature1()` function should have a return type (`void` given that it doesn't return a value).  Also, it calculates but ignores `angle2`, so the code doesn't even need `convert_to_rad()`.  In general, it is also a good idea to end `printf()` outputs with a newline.   I can see that the code is example code, but it is as well to ensure you're compiling with options that force you to declare (or define) functions before you use them.  With GCC, `-Wmissing-prototypes` and `-Wstrict-prototypes` combine to do that; there are other related options too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Perhaps `-Wall` is the better option

Comment: @EdHeal: Well, it depends on whether you also specify a language version for C99 or C11 compliance.  Yes, `-Wall` should be used; so should `-Wextra`, and even `-Werror`, and I use `-Wold-style-declaration` and `-Wold-style-definition` (one of which is part of `-Wall` or `-Wextra`, but the other isn't, so I write both so I don't have to remember which is which), along with `-std=c11` (and usually `-g -O3` too).  And the warnings you get from the assemblage depends on which version of GCC you have; they change over time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler = Basically turn on all the warnings/make them errors. Cannot go far wrong with that

Comment: @EdHeal: Pretty much!  It's a pity that `-Wall` doesn't turn them all on (or, perhaps, it is a misnomer that everyone who's been around a while recognizes as such), and `-Wextra` is a better name. Very little of the code I write for SO fails to compile cleanly under the options I use — `-O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition`.  I occasionally add a few options to that panoply, such as `-Wshadow`, but I seldom need that on a routine basis.

Comment: this line: angle_in_rad = (angle_in_deg * M_PI) / 180; is forcing a type conversion from int to double, at run time.  better to write the line as: angle_in_rad = (angle_in_deg * M_PI) / 180.0;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not fix the formatting?

Anyhow use a forward declaration.

i.e. place

```
double convert_to_rad(double angle_in_deg);
```

At the start (before `feature1` function)

Comment: First, thanks a lot, that fixed the problem. Second, I'm in a rush, strict university deadline, sorry to have caused offence.

Comment: Or, another option is to define `convert_to_rad()` before you call it.